# Qual è il significato di "panoplia" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> La piazza fu ornata con cartelli di benvenuto, festoni e tavoli con **panoplie** di cibarie.

Non capisco il significato di "panoplie" in questa frase. L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari e ho trovato che si tratta di una armatura, ma questo non sembra avere molto senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Sto cercando un dizionario che sia d'accordo con me per una risposta, ma ho sempre sentito usare *panoplia* come sinonimo di *abbondanza*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dal Devoto-Oli:

> **panoplia** ‹pa·nò·plia› **s.f.**
>
> 1. Il complesso delle varie parti di un’armatura, o un insieme di armi assortite, disposte a trofeo per ornamento, o in quanto soggetto di raffigurazione plastica o pittorica a carattere decorativo.
> 2. *fig.* Assortimento estremamente vario e pittoresco.
>
> **ETIMO** Dal gr. *panoplía*, comp. di *pân* ‘tutto’ e *hóplon* ‘arma’
>
> **DATA** sec. XVIII.
>
> **SINONIMI** armatura completa, armi assortite, assortimento, varietà

In questo caso il significato inteso è il secondo, vale a dire la frase potrebbe essere riscritta come

> La piazza fu ornata con cartelli di benvenuto, festoni e tavoli con assortimenti di cibarie.

Non so perché pochi dizionari lo riportino, ma nella mia esperienza il secondo significato è di gran lunga il più comune.

Comment: Pqcv, avevo presente solo il primo senso, che comunque mi sembra adatto a un uso traslato per indicare qualsiasi altra disposizione ricca e curata di oggetti, non solo armi e parti di armatura.

Comment: Il secondo significato è chiaramente una versione figurata del primo. Si tratta in ogni caso di una parola poco comune, per cui è più che possibile che sia una coincidenza che io abbia incontrato essenzialmente solo il senso figurato nelle mie letture.

Comment: Lo Zingarelli riporta anche, per estensione, "insieme di oggetti esposti", che può essere applicato al caso in oggetto, pur non suggerendo abbondanza.

Answer (score 1):

Come dici correttamente [**panoplia**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/panoplia/) significa:

> **panòplia** s. f. [dal gr. πανοπλία, comp. di παν- «pan-» e ὅπλον
>   «arma»]. – 1. Armatura completa, e in partic., presso gli antichi
>   Greci, l’armatura degli opliti. 2. Insieme di armi, generalm. bianche,
>   o di varie parti di un’armatura, disposte come trofeo, per lo più su
>   parete, a scopo decorativo. Anche la raffigurazione pittorica o
>   plastica di tale insieme, in uso spec. nel Rinascimento, e anche nel
>   periodo dell’arte neoclassica, nella decorazione architettonica o in
>   monumenti celebrativi.

Nel passaggio da te indicato, come la panoplia era un insieme completo di armatura, armi da attacco e difesa, si usa questo termine per indicare che sulla tavola c'erano tutti i tipi di cibarie che una persona potesse desiderare, dai primi piatti fino ad arrivare ai dolci.